# Ion-Label and Ion-Input does not announce the label on hybrid android app when using talkback

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, accessibility, talkback

Talkback does not announce the label associated with the input when ion-input is focused. I've attached ARIA attributes associated for the screen readers to read the messages without any luck.

```
 <ion-label for="hoursInput" aria-label="Hours" required aria-required="true" class="label-name"
                style="margin-bottom:8px">
                <span style="color: maroon; font-weight: bold;">* </span>
                <span>Hours</span>
 </ion-label>
 <ion-input id="hoursInput" placeholder="0" aria-required="true"
                  aria-labelledby="Enter Hours Required" formControlName="hours"
                  type="text" aria-describedby="hoursdesc">
   </ion-input>
```